# HttpServletRequest gets lost once every three requests

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-webflow

Despite of being hard to choose a title for my question, here is the problem.

For my login page, I have managed to use spring web flow. One of the main stages in login process is that, if the user is trying to login and has provided wrong username and password more than three times, there should be a `captcha verification` as well. Hence, here is the captcha class:

```
public final class CaptchaErrorCountAction extends AbstractAction {

   private String COUNT       = "count";
   private String SHOWCAPTCHA = "showCaptcha";

   protected Event doExecute(final RequestContext context) {
      Integer count;
      HttpServletRequest request = WebUtils.getHttpServletRequest(context);
      try {
        count = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("count");
        if (count == null) {
           count = 0;
        }
       } catch (Exception e) {
       count = 0;
      }
      count++;
      request.getSession().setAttribute(COUNT, count);
      request.getSession().setAttribute(SHOWCAPTCHA, true);
      return success();
     }
  }
```

In google chrome, everything is fine and the `count` variable shows the number of failed login attempts with a simple break point. But in firefox, `3rd, 6th, 9th, ...` failed login attempts never gets to count++ and seemly gets lots. what would seem to be the problem?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are saying. Did you try using break points in the `doExecute(..)` method and try to execute the code line by line?

Comment: that was the first thing I did. the problem is, when the application is running in google chrome the excution arrives at break point for every request, but in firefox there is one lost. I mean, after two failed login attempts, the value for count is exactly two, but for the third time, not only we have break point escape, but also the value of count still remains two.

Comment: That sure is strange. This shouldn't really have anything to do with the browser since all of the code is on the server side. Does the execution point get anywhere inside the `doExecute()` block?

Comment: negative. but I have to add that there are multiple filters applied on application in web.xml e.g. decoder, security, ..

Comment: Then one of those filters might be the culprit preventing the code from executing.

Comment: Add some logging and see if your server method gets executed properly.

Comment: I'll double check that. hope to find the solution through this.